# The difference between pointer in 2D and 1D array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I practiced today some C code, especially array with return function and pointers.
And I found some code which were really confusing and want to know why it is.

So I have first a function which print all elements out of the array.

```
void function(int *arr)
{
    ...
    printf("%d, arr[i]);
}
```

Now in main I have a 2D array and a 1D array.

```
int array2D[2][2] = {{1,2}, {3,4}};
int array1D[3] = {1,2,3};

function(*array2D); // Why do I need here the derefernce pointer
function(array1D);  // why I don't need here the deference pointer
```

And in another case:

```
void disp( int *num)
{
    printf("%d ", *num);
}

int main()
{
    int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0};
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        /* Passing addresses of array elements*/
        disp(&arr[i]); // why i need here & and above in the function not
    }
}
```

This is really confusing me right now.  Can someone explain me this?

Comment: `*array2D` is equivalent to `array2D[0]` and of type `int[2]`. It's all about types.

Comment: What do you mean by 'why i need here & and above in the function not' ?

Comment: @deadcode above we didnt use any of adress operator & for running through the element (look function(int*array) why i do need this in this example?

Comment: Ok I get your question now and Pablo explains it well.

Answer (score 4):

The first line

```
function(*array2D);
```

is equivalent to

```
function(array2D[0]);
```

So you are passing the first array `[1,2]`. In C an array decays into a pointer
when it is passed to a function.

However, your `function` function<sup>1</sup> should also get the number of
elements of the array.

```
void function(int *arr, size_t len)
{
    size_t i;
    for(i = 0; i < len; ++i)
        printf("%d\n", arr[i]);
}
```

Then you can call it<sup>2</sup>

```
int array2D[2][2] = { { 1,2} ,{3,4}};
int array1D[3] = {1,2,3};

function(*array2D, sizeof *array2D / sizeof **array2D);
function(array1D, sizeof array1D / sizeof *array1D);
```

---

> ```
>   disp (&arr[i]); // why i need here & and above in the function not
> ```

Because `arr[i]` would give you the value stored at the position `i`, `disp`
expects a pointer, so you use the `&`-operator which returns the address of the
array at the position `i`, which is also equivalent to `arr + i`.

---

<sup>1</sup>Don't call your functions `function`. Technically that is valid name, but it
would be better if you give your function more explicit names so that just by
reading the name, you know what the functions does.

<sup>2</sup>Note that `sizeof array / sizeof *array` only works with arrays. If you have a
function and you expect an array, you will get only a pointer to the array.
In this case you also would need to pass the length of the array.

Answer (score 0):

We're used to the fact that `int mike[10]` decays to `int *`, which points to the first thing in the array.  So it seems like `int sam[5][10]` might also decay to `int *`  pointing to the first element of the array.  But `int sam[5][10]` is not a "two-dimensional array of int" that decays to an int pointer, it's an array of five arrays of ten integers.  The first thing in `sam` is the first of the five arrays, so `sam` decays to a pointer to an array of ten integers, which type is written `int (*)[10]`, though it rarely *is* written.

So your array2D decays to a different type than integer pointer, which is why your call `function(array2D);` creates a type mismatch.  But your call `function(*array2D);` does work because (as noted above) `*array2D` is the same as `array2D[0]`, which is an array of integers, and does decay to `int *`.

For your second case, `arr` is an array, but `arr[i]` is an `int`, since it is just one position in the array.  The ampersand operator makes a pointer of what it operates, so `&arr[i]` is a pointer, and the call works.